# Is it consistent that every $x \in H(\omega_1)$ is an element of an "inner model" of $H(\omega_1)$?

Tags: set-theory

Is the following consistent with $\mathrm{ZFC}$? For every $x \in H(\omega_1)$, there is a transitive set $X \subseteq H(\omega_1)$ of height $\omega_1$ such that firstly, $(X,\in\restriction_X)$ satisfies $\mathrm{ZFC}$, and secondly, $x$ is an element of $X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Start with $V=L$ and $\kappa$ is inaccessible. Now collapse $\kappa$ using $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,<\kappa)$. Namely, we make every ordinal smaller than $\kappa$ countable, and indeed we can see this forcing as a product of forcings which add surjections from $\omega$ to $\alpha$, for every $\alpha<\kappa$. So at the end of the forcing, $\kappa$ is $\omega_1$. This is our universe now.

Given $x\in H(\omega_1)$ there is some $\alpha<\kappa$ such that $x$ was added by the collapses up to $\alpha$, meaning there is some $A$ which is a generic for the relevant part of the forcing. In fact, $A$ itself can be taken as a real number.

So consider $L_\kappa[A]$, since $\kappa$ is strongly inaccessible in $L[A]$, this is a model of $\sf ZFC$, and certainly $x\in L[A]$. So we have that $x\in L_\kappa[A]$.